# Can't write to a file. Oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, directory

I'm trying to execute these lines:

```
DECLARE
    V_FILEHANDLE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
    V_FILEHANDLE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C:\samples', '1.csv', 'w');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_FILEHANDLE, 'sample string');
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE_ALL;
END;
```

Previously I've successfully executed these statements:

```
create directory sample as 'C:\samples';
```

(though I can't find the directory on the `C:\` drive?)
But this gives me an output like:

> ORA-29280: "invalid directory path"
>
> ***Cause**: A corresponding directory object does not exist.
>
> ***Action**: Correct the directory object parameter, or create a corresponding directory object with the CREATE DIRECTORY command.

Also I've tried to grant previleges to my username:

```
grant read, write on directory sample to brick;
```

But this gives me an output like

> ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
V_FILEHANDLE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C:\samples', '1.csv', 'w');
```

with :

```
V_FILEHANDLE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('SAMPLE', '1.csv', 'w');
```

As [indicated in the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#i1003526), the first parameter is the directory object *name*.

---

In older versions of Oracle, the first parameter of `UTL_FILE.open` [used to be the directory path](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76936/utl_fil2.htm#1000987), but this has been deprecated since the introduction of the `DIRECTORY` object (in 9i?).

Comment: Done.. Now getting ORA-29283 error. Who should I grant permissions?

Comment: @brick Does the directory physically exist on the server? You have to create the directory from the OS before using it in Oracle.

Comment: I didn't know this, as you might guess)

Comment: Should I grant any permissions to a stored procedure to modify directory/files?

Comment: The permissions on a directory is [granted at the database user level](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9013.htm#BGBCIIEG), so any procedure owned by a granted user will be able to access the directory. All rights are automatically granted to the creator of an object directory. Afterwards, rights can be granted to other users by DBA users (with [CREATE ANY DIRECTORY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5007.htm#i2061958) system right I think).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SOOO MUCH! I found my error. I was creating the directory like

```html
create or REPLACE DIRECTORY dat_dir as '/u01/oracle/Desktop/Migration/Data';
```

Then I used it in my UTL_FILE like this

```html
file1 := utl_file.fopen('dat_dir','output.txt','w');
```

I've been trying this to work for 3 days now. I found the problem, since it's in quotation mark, it's a case sensitive string. It doesn't matter if initially I tiped dat_dir, oracle stores things like this in uppercase. Your simple answer helped me realize this, thank you a million times!

The right way to do it was:

```html
file1 := utl_file.fopen('DAT_DIR','output.txt','w');
```